# change display name C# to send email

Tags: c#, email, smtp, office365

I am sending mail with C#. I like change the display name dinamic.

```
string sender = "myemail@domain.com";
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sender, "mypassword");
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            MailAddress froms = new MailAddress(sender, "Name Name");
            //MailAddress froms = new MailAddress(sender, "Name Name", Encoding.ASCII);
            //MailAddress froms = new MailAddress(sender, "Name Name", Encoding.UTF8);
            //MailAddress froms = new MailAddress(sender, "Name Name", Encoding.Unicode);
            //MailAddress froms = new MailAddress(sender, "\\MyDisplayName\\");
            //MailAddress froms = new MailAddress(sender);                

            mail.From = froms;
            mail.Sender = new MailAddress(de);
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@domain"));
            mail.Subject = "TEST";
            mail.Body = "body";
            smtp.Send(mail);
```

but the "Name Name" is ignored and always send mail with the Name configurated in Outlook

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think office 365 will let you override the name.

Comment: If you are using an installed version of Outlook, you could refer to this link: https://www.matthewproctor.com/extracting-email-addresses-from-outlook-using-c-sharp

Comment: Did you solve it?